# Remote printer discovery via Windows API

Tags: windows, powershell, printing, sccm, service-discovery

In a Windows network where each computer runs an SCCM client, is there any way of discovering and listing the Printer objects available to one machine, via an API call from another?

Can this be done via SCCM, Powershell, or any REST library?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean with "via an API call from another [machine]" in regards to sccm? With sccm you could just deploy something to the machine you want info from, so I see no need to do it via a different one. With powershell you could basically always use enter-pssession to connect to the machine and run your non remote api commands from there

Comment: Powershell's Get-Printer command accepts the "-ComputerName" parameter to allow you to query the installed printers on another computer. Not sure what this question really has to do with SCCM, or were you offering that as a possible access method?
Frankly if you've got SCCM then the inventory is all you need to know what printers are on each computer.